# How to use `updateTraitsIfNeeded` - when to call it?

Tags: swift, uikit

There's a new function [`updateTraitsIfNeeded()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/4273800-updatetraitsifneeded) available for iOS 17+ and I'm wondering - what is its use case, when should I call it? The documentation seems to be empty.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the function documentation in Xcode, I was able to find out

> Forces an immediate trait update for this view (and its view controller, if applicable) and any subviews,
> including any view controllers or views in its subtree. Any trait change callbacks are sent synchronously.